# Using setTimeout on promise chain

Tags: javascript, json, promise, settimeout

Here i am trying to wrap my head around promises.Here on first request i fetch a set of links.and on next request i fetch the content of first link.But i want to make a delay before returning next promise object.So i use setTimeout on it. But it gives me the following JSON error (**`without setTimeout() it works just fine`**)

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
> the JSON data

***i would like to know why it fails?***

```
let globalObj={};
function getLinks(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
       
       let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
       http.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(http.readyState == 4){
              if(http.status == 200){
                resolve(http.response);
              }else{
                reject(new Error());
              }
            }           
       }
       http.open("GET",url,true);
       http.send();
    });
}

getLinks('links.txt').then(function(links){
    let all_links = (JSON.parse(links));
    globalObj=all_links;

    return getLinks(globalObj["one"]+".txt");

}).then(function(topic){
    
    
    writeToBody(topic);
    setTimeout(function(){
         return getLinks(globalObj["two"]+".txt"); // without setTimeout it works fine 
         },1000);
});
```

Comment: Note that `return` is function specific, and returns only to the parent function, and that you can't return from an async method.

Comment: Notice there are [much better ways](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) to structure this code than to use a `globalObj`.

Comment: Where does `JSON.parse` throw? I find it hard to believe that whether there is a `setTimeout` in one `then` callback affects the call in the previous `then` callback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Answer (score 270, accepted):

To keep the promise chain going, you can't use `setTimeout()` the way you did because you aren't returning a promise from the `.then()` handler - you're returning it from the `setTimeout()` callback which does you no good.

Instead, you can make a simple little delay function like this:

```
function delay(t, val) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t, val));
}
```

And, then use it like this:

```
getLinks('links.txt').then(function(links){
    let all_links = (JSON.parse(links));
    globalObj=all_links;

    return getLinks(globalObj["one"]+".txt");

}).then(function(topic){
    writeToBody(topic);
    // return a promise here that will be chained to prior promise
    return delay(1000).then(function() {
        return getLinks(globalObj["two"]+".txt");
    });
});
```

Here you're returning a promise from the `.then()` handler and thus it is chained appropriately.

---

You can also add a delay method to the Promise object and then directly use a `.delay(x)` method on your promises like this:

```js
function delay(t, val) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t, val));
}

Promise.prototype.delay = function(t) {
    return this.then(function(val) {
        return delay(t, val);
    });
}


Promise.resolve("hello").delay(500).then(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: resolve function is the function inside then()..so setTimeout(resolve,t) means the setTimeout(function(){ return ....},t) isn't it...so why it will work?

Comment: @AL-zami - `delay()` returns a promise that will be resolved after the `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I've created a promise wrapper for setTimeout to easily delay a promise. https://github.com/zengfenfei/delay

Comment: @pdem - `v` is an optional value that you would like the delay promise to resolve with and thus pass down the promise chain.  `resolve.bind(null, v)` is in place of `function() {resolve(v);}`  Either will work.

Comment: thank you so much... the prototype delay worked but not the function >>> .then statement.  the t was undefined.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew - The `t` value comes from what you pass `delay(t)` so if you had an undefined `t`, it's probably in how you were  calling it.

Comment: @jfriend00 can you explain why do we need `resolve.bind(null, v)`? I tried to change it directly to `resolve(v)`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @LeoShi - You need the `resolve(v)` to be called LATER when the actual `setTimeout()` timer fires (when it calls its callback).  If you just use `resolve(v)`, that calls it immediately BEFORE the timer fires.  As an example, you could also do `setTimeout(() => resolve(v), t)`.  Also, you have to pass a callback to `setTimeout()` to be able to use the timer.    Passing `resolve(v)` executes `resolve(v)` immediately and passes the return value from executing that which is `undefined` so you aren't passing a callback and don't get any notification when the timer fires.

Comment: Hmmm.... I believe this creates a blocking call though. I am not sure if this is what the OP intended, but if you were to call `delay` and then call something after it, the thing after it wouldn't be called until the `delay` is completed, which is not OK (or shouldn't be). Do you have any ideas how to mitigate this?

Comment: @RobertVunabandi - It's not blocking (other things can run during the delay), but it intentionally calls the next function AFTER a delay.  That is the entire point here.  There's no point in using a function like `delay()` if you don't want to call something LATER.  This answer shows one how to insert a purposeful delay into a promise chain.  That's what this does.

Comment: `Promise.prototype.delay=function(t) {return this.then((v) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(()=>r(v),t)))};`  

Comment: also, if you add `Promise.timeout = function (t, v) { return Promise.resolve(v).delay(t);}`  lets you do `Promise.timeout(500,"hello").then(console.log.bind(console))` (2nd argument is optional)

Comment: Beautiful! Worked like a charm. Thank you so much! I returned it from my function, then used async/await when I called my function, and the delay happened as expected. My version: ```function wait(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve.bind(null), time);
  });
}```

Comment: @user1305454 - I updated the `delay()` implementation to be a bit simpler.

Comment: descriptive variable names would make this answer stronger.

Comment: @lowcrawler - Which variable names are you thinking of with that comment?  I changed `v` to `val`, but not sure what else you were referring to.

Comment: `You can also add a delay method to the Promise object and then directly use a .delay(x)` That's clever. A lot of people assume a Promise prototype and a Promise instance can't be modified, as though it's been `Object.freeze()`'d. While I'm not sure if this is a good practice, it can create some great APIs. Testcafe's API, as an example, returns a `interface TestControllerPromise<T=any> extends TestController, Promise<T> {}`, allowing you to chain calls like so: `await testController.click(...).expect(...).eql(...).click(...)...`

Comment: @DanielKaplan -  I don't think that these days I would advise adding methods to the built-in Promise or prototype.  Extending built-in objects by adding methods to them is just not generally considered a good idea.  Promises are sub-classable if you really want to extend them, but since most promises come from some other source, that subclassing often doesn't really help much since you'll usually get a plain promise from the outside world.

Comment: @jfriend00 for the delay(t ,val) function you created, is it possible to know is it correct that you could in general just pass in 1 argument even if you have more than 1 possible arguments in the function (like here you only give the argument 500 to the delay(t ,val) function, also is it assumed that this 500 value is an argument to the t not the val parameters?: Promise.resolve("hello").delay(500).then(function(val) {
    console.log(val);

Comment: @john_w - If you pass only a single argument, it will be the first argument which is `t`.  The 2nd argument `val` will be `undefined` (which is an actual value in Javascript) since you didn't pass it.

Comment: @jfriend00 so "undefined" is an actual valid value in javascript as well? Also then must always return a Promise, so that's why we have to find some way to attach "something that returns a Promise" at the end of the "then"? is it the rationale of the answer? sorry I am very beginner of typescript.

Comment: @john_w - Yes, `undefined` is an actual value in Javascript.  You return a promise when you want the return value to be a promise that can be resolved/rejected at some time in the future.  I'm not sure what else you mean by your previous comment.

Answer (score 152):

```
.then(() => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 15000)))
```

UPDATE:

when I need sleep in async function I throw in

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
```

Answer (score 101):

The shorter ES6 version of the answer:

```
const delay = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
```

And then you can do:

```
delay(3000).then(() => console.log('Hello'));
```

Comment: and if you need the `reject` option, e.g for eslint validation, then `const delay = ms => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))`

Comment: See how to use this in a Mocha test -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70348823/1019307

Answer (score 15):

If you are inside a **.then()** block and you want to execute a **settimeout()**

```
            .then(() => {
                console.log('wait for 10 seconds . . . . ');
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.log('10 seconds Timer expired!!!');
                        resolve();
                    }, 10000)
                });
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('promise resolved!!!');

            })
```

output will as shown below

```
wait for 10 seconds . . . .
10 seconds Timer expired!!!
promise resolved!!!
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 15):

Since node v15, you can use [timers promise API](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timerspromisessettimeoutdelay-value-options)

example from the doc:

```js
import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises'

const res = await setTimeout(100, 'result')

console.log(res)  // Prints 'result'
```

Answer (score 4):

In node.js you can also do the following:

```js
const { promisify } = require('util')
const delay = promisify(setTimeout)

delay(1000).then(() => console.log('hello'))
```

Comment: I tried this and got invalid number of arguments, expected 0 within the delay function.

Comment: I can confirm it works in node.js 8, 10, 12, 13. Not sure how you're running your code but I can only assume `util` is being polyfilled incorrectly. Are you using a bundler or something?

Answer (score 1):

For the current LTS its easier and we can use async/await to handle timeouts. Please note that this is the recommended way to use timeout nowadays.

Thenables is not the recommended way.

```
const { promisify } = require('util')
const sleep = promisify(setTimeout)
async function myFunction() {
  await sleep(1e3)
  console.log('This will be seen after 1 sec')
  await sleep(5e3)
  console.log('This will be seen after 5 sec after')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const myStuff = new Promise(function (resolve) {
  console.log("before timeout");
  setTimeout(
    function (x) {
      console.log("inside the timeout");
      resolve(x);
    },
    3000,
    "after timeout"
  );
}).then((response) => console.log(response));
```