# Using when and done and settimeout show hide div

Tags: jquery, settimeout, show-hide

```js
function closecustomBox() {
  $('#dialog').hide();
}
$('#dialog').hide();
$('#anotherdialog').hide();
$("#show").click(function() {
  $('#dialog').show();
  $.when(
    setTimeout(function() {
      closecustomBox();
    }, 3000)
  ).done(function(x) {
    $('#anotherdialog').show();
  });
})
```

```css
#dialog {
  width: 101px;
  height: 101px;
  background-color: red;
}

#anotherdialog {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog"></div>

<div id="anotherdialog"></div>


<div id="show">show</div>
```

What I want to happened is after clicking show will show the red box after 3 seconds the red box will hide then the blue box should show.

> I want to achieve here is to not make the 2 div appear together

Comment: Although the question is different, the answer here should be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39538518/2181514

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using setTimeout on promise chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538473/using-settimeout-on-promise-chain)

Comment: @freedomn-m im reading it i cant see how it is dup though

Comment: If I was to take the answer to that question and paste it here, it would be a valid answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to use `$.when` then you need to pass in a `$.Deferred()` as an argument. Then resolve the `$.Deferred()` once the timeout completes which will call the method that we passed to `.done()` previously.

I also set the initial state of the dialogs via CSS to `display: none;` to avoid the need for hiding them via JS initially.

I've also provided an alternative which doesn't use jQuery deferred's which achieves the same results.

```js
function closecustomBox() {
  $('#dialog').hide();
}

var dialog = $('#dialog');
var anotherDialog = $('#anotherdialog');
var timeout;

$("#show").click(function() {
  dialog.show();
  anotherDialog.hide();

  def = $.Deferred();
  $.when(def).done(function() {
    closecustomBox();
    anotherDialog.show();
  });

  if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout); // Clear out any old timeouts to avoid flickers and strange behavior
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    def.resolve(); // Resolve the Deferred which will call def.done's callback
  }, 3000);
})

// Or if you don't want to use promises you can just elminate them entirely and simplify this example greatly
var timeout2;
 $("#show-2").click(function() {
      dialog.show();
      anotherDialog.hide();

      if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout); // Clear out any old timeouts to avoid flickers and strange behavior
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        closecustomBox();
        anotherDialog.show();
      }, 3000);
    })
```

```css
#anotherdialog {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
}

#dialog {
  width: 101px;
  height: 101px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog"></div>

<div id="anotherdialog"></div>


<div id="show">show</div>

<div id="show-2">Alternate Show</div>
```

Comment: i need something like this great answer

Comment: Glad to be of assistance, I've just updated the answer with a simplified second example that eliminates the need for Deferred :).

Answer (score 0):

Small change to your code..

```js
function closecustomBox() {
  $('#dialog').hide();
}
$('#dialog').hide();
$('#anotherdialog').hide();
$("#show").click(function() {
  $('#dialog').show();
  //$.when(
    setTimeout(function() {
      closecustomBox();
      $('#anotherdialog').show();
    }, 3000)
  /*).done(function(x) {
    $('#anotherdialog').show();
  });*/
})
```

```css
#dialog {
  width: 101px;
  height: 101px;
  background-color: red;
}

#anotherdialog {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog"></div>

<div id="anotherdialog"></div>


<div id="show">show</div>
```

Comment: Question *"use when and done"* answer: comment out when and done... eh?

Answer (score 0):

`$.when` is taking input parameters, when those resolve, then it will excute the `done` function. In your case `setTimeout` function is executed successfully, so it is calling `done` method instantly without waiting to upto `3sec`. To make it work, you need to use `Promise` concept here.

```js
function closecustomBox() {
  $('#dialog').hide();
}
$('#dialog').hide();
$('#anotherdialog').hide();
$("#show").click(function() {
  $('#dialog').show();
  var $def = $.Deferred();
  $.when(
    $def
  ).done(function(x) {
    $('#anotherdialog').show();
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    closecustomBox();
    $def.resolve(true);
  }, 3000);
})
```

```css
#dialog {
  width: 101px;
  height: 101px;
  background-color: red;
}

#anotherdialog {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog"></div>

<div id="anotherdialog"></div>


<div id="show">show</div>
```