# Is there a way to guarantee `Promise.all` resolves after the `then` chain of an inner promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Is there a way to guarantee `Promise.all` resolves after the `then` chain of an inner promise?

Example:

```
const promiseOne = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('promiseOne after 1 second')
    resolve()
  }, 1000)
}).then(()=> {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('promiseOne then chain, after 2 seconds')
  }, 1000)
})


Promise.all([promiseOne])
.then(() => {
  console.log('Promise.all then chain after 1 second')
})
```

Logs:

```
promiseOne after 1 second
Promise.all then chain after 1 second
promiseOne then chain, after 2 seconds
```

Comment: Return another promise that resolves after 1 sec in your "promiseOne then chain, after 2 seconds" callback. Right now your callback returns undefined. and is resolved immediately.

Comment: that's how promise.all works, and using it for a single promise is redundant anyway

Comment: Your answer is here [Using setTimeout in a promise chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538473/using-settimeout-on-promise-chain/39538518#39538518).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `then`s are running in the correct order, but the first one is simply setting a timeout, so the `console.log`s run in the opposite order to the `then`s.  If you want to wait for that timeout to run before continuing the chain, you need to use an additional promise returned from that `then`:

```js
const promiseOne = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('promiseOne after 1 second')
    resolve()
  }, 1000)
}).then(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('promiseOne then chain, after 2 seconds')
    resolve()
  }, 1000)
  })
)


Promise.all([promiseOne])
.then(() => {
  console.log('Promise.all then chain after 1 second')
})
```

Comment: sigh can't believe i didnt notice that

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to pass the promise returned by the last `then`, which you are already doing. If you take your console log in the first `then` out of the `setTimeout` you'll see that it is executing in the order you want.

The reason it's logging in that order is because `setTimeout` is asynchronous.

Try like so:

```
const promiseOne = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('promiseOne after 1 second')
    resolve()
  }, 1000)
}).then(()=> new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('promiseOne then chain, after 2 seconds')
    resolve()
  }, 1000)
})
```

By having the first `then` return a promise, it will wait till after your `setTimeout` and continue in the correct order.

EDIT: As a bonus, when using `setTimeout`s, this helper is super useful:

```
const wait = ms => () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,ms));
```

Which you can use like so:

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(wait(2000))
.then(() => {
  doSomething();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a new promise in the then chain of the inner promise:

```js
const promiseOne = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('promiseOne after 1 second')
    resolve();
  }, 1000)
}).then(()=> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('promiseOne then chain, after 2 seconds');
      resolve();
    }, 1000)  
  });
})

Promise.all([promiseOne])
.then(() => {
  console.log('Promise.all then chain after 1 second')
})
```