# Shouldn't async return a Promise without explicitly wrapping the return value in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) states that

> When an async function is called, it returns a Promise. When the async
>   function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the
>   returned value.  When the async function throws an exception or some
>   value, the Promise will be rejected with the thrown value.

Therefore, what am I doing wrong, considering that `await` expects a resolved promise?

```js
foo();

async function foo(){
    await bar();
    zoo();
}

async function bar(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("bar");
        return;
    }, 1000);    
}

function zoo(){
    console.log("zoo");    
}
```

According to what I (wrongly) understood, it should first log `bar` and then `zoo`, but it's logging the other way around.

**EDIT:** Now, thanks to clarifications from @Matt Morgan, I understand the mistake, as the `bar()` function returns `undefined`. Nonetheless, I thought that by calling an `async` function *per se* alone would make the function return immediately an unresolved promise and that such promise would be resolved when the `async` function would return any value (even undefined). But I now realise one really needs to return a promise oneself by declaring it with `return Promise` statement. I think the MDN article for `async`, which I read it all, is a bit confusing on this topic (just my opinion).

Therefore I could simply amend my `bar()` function to:

```
function bar(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("bar");
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: In the link you just posted, go look at the code for `resolveAfter2Seconds`, then compare it to your bar().  Notice something?

Comment: @Will, I read all that article plus the example, but I don't understand why you need to return a `Promise` if the async function already returns a `Promise` by simply running `return;`. The documentation says "when an async function is called, it returns a Promise. When the async function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the returned value"

Comment: @Will Therefore "I know how to make it work", I simply don't understand why it does work like that `:)`

Comment: Interesting. Returns are automatically wrapped in a promise. That sure cuts down on the boilerplate. Neat.

Comment: *”Nonetheless, I thought that by calling an async function per se alone would make the function return immediately an unresolved promise and that such promise would be resolved when the async function would return any value (even undefined)”* that’s exactly how async functions work. However, `bar` does immedeatly return `undefined`. It does not (and cannot) wait for the timeout to finish. For that to work you have to construct the promise yourself.

Comment: @Felix Kling 1) why `bar` returns immediately if I just `return` after the timeout is finished? 2) if it cannot wait for the timeout to finish, why do I need an `async` function? Just to embed `await` calls?

Comment: 1) `return` doesn’t cross function boundaries. You are returning inside the callback only. The function will return to its caller. But you are not the caller of the callback, the browser will call the function when the timeout is up. The cal to `setTimeout` itself returns immediately. It’s not blocking. 2) If you explicitly create and return a promise, then you don’t need async. If you want to be able to use await inside a function, you need async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bar()` is setting the timeout and returning undefined, which is not the same as immediately running the logging statement that runs when the timeout finishes.

So, `zoo()` runs, and then when the timeout finishes (1000ms later), you see "bar" in the console.

Here's a modified example *without* the timeout:

```js
foo();

async function foo(){
    await bar();
    zoo();
}

async function bar(){
   console.log("bar");   
}

function zoo(){
    console.log("zoo");    
}
```

With no `setTimeout`, you get the order of execution you expect.

A second example, where you have a `delay()` function that wraps `setTimeout` in a promise:

```js
foo();

async function foo(){
    await bar();
    zoo();
}

async function bar(){
   await delay();
   console.log("bar");   
}

function delay(t, v) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
       setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, v), t)
   });
}

function zoo(){
    console.log("zoo");    
}
```

The final snippet *does* wait for the resolution of the promise, so you see `bar`, then `foo`.

The above `delay` was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39538518/3084820

Here's a final example, where `bar()` returns "bar".  This means it gets wrapped in a promise by the `async` declaration, and resolved by the `await` inside `foo()`  Again, you see what you expected to see.

```js
foo();

async function foo(){
    console.log(await bar());
    zoo();
}

async function bar(){
    return 'bar';   
}

function zoo(){
    console.log("zoo");    
}
```

It's important to understand the your original example *does not return the value `bar`*.  It returns `undefined`, and if you change your original code to log out the returned value of `bar()`, you would see three things in the console:

1. The immediately returned promise form `bar()` that resolves to `undefined`.
2. The value `zoo` from the `zoo()` function.
3. Finally, after 1000ms elapsed, you would see the `bar` logged from the `setTimeout` that got shoved on the queue.

Try it, see what you get.

Comment: thanks for replying, I understand your code perfectly. In your first example, there is no need to `async`, it is merely a sequence of commands; in your second example which I have already used, you return a `Promise`, but I don't understand why you need to return a `Promise` if the async function already returns a `Promise` by simply running `return`

Comment: The function `bar` returns `undefined`.  In your original code, you're setting a timeout, which really doesn't have anything to do with promises.  In order to test the async behavior, you need to have a promise that resolves when the timeout completes, which is why I included the second example.

Comment: ok, but MDN documentation says that "when an async function is called, it returns a Promise. When the async function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the returned value". That made confused!

Comment: And the promise is immediately resolved with a value of `undefined`.  I think you're getting confused in thinking that the resolution of the promise will result in the `console.log` statement getting executed.

Comment: but if there is a promise (I don't care for the purpose of the code, what value will be), shouldn't `await` wait for the resolution of the `promise`? Why is immediately resolved if I just `return` later?

Comment: `setTimeout` leverages a browser API that inserts the wrapped function into the queue after a certain amount of time.  It does not create a promise.  Your function sets the timeout, then returns `undefined`, and the promise resolves with a value of `undefined`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164578/discussion-between-matt-morgan-and-joao-pimentel-ferreira).

Comment: I marked your solution as The solution, but I still don't understand why the `async` function doesn't return a returned promise when it simply returns. The documentation says "When an async function is called, it returns a Promise. When the async function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the returned value." Apologies if I'm being persistent!

Comment: Therefore "I know how to make it work", I simply don't understand why it does work like that `:)`

Comment: Thanks again! Now I see that it simply returns `undefined`. I thought that by calling `async` _per se_ would make the function return immediately an unresolved promise and that such promise would be resolved when the `async` function would return any value (even undefined). But I now I see you really need to return a promise yourself by declaring it with `return Promise` statement. I think the MDN article for `async`, which I read it all, is a bit confusing on this topic (just my opinion). Anyway, thanks a lot!