# Parse multi chain promises with a sequential for loop

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

In the code below, I am trying to do the following:

- Have `Stats()`, `getOverallStats()` and `GetGroups()` to run in parallel. Each returns a promise.
- The `forEach` in `GetGroups.then()` should run sequentially to ensure the output is in the correct order.
- Once ALL of the above is complete, then run some more code.

However, I am getting very confused with the promises! The logging gives me:

```
looping
here
looping
looping
```

But what I am looking for is `here` to be at the end.

Finally, at the moment I have hardcoded `loopAgelist[1]` for testing purposes. But, I actually want to be able to loop through `loopAgelist[]` with a timeout in between! I would appreciate if someone could explain some promise 'rules' to use in these complicated cases.

```
    var loopAgeList;
    var looppromises = [];
    getAgeGroupList().then(function (loopAgeList) {
        var statsPromise = Stats(loopAgeList[1]);
        var oStatsPromise = getOverallStats();
        var grpPromise = GetGroups(loopAgeList[1]).then(function (groups) {
            var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
            groups.forEach(function (grp) {
                promise = promise.then(function () {    // Need this so that the tables are drawn in the correct order (force to be in series)
                    console.log("looping")
                    if (grp != "KO"){
                        var standingsPromise = Standings(loopAgeList[1], grp);
                        looppromises.push(standingsPromise);
                    }

                    var fixPromise = GetFixtures(loopAgeList[1], grp);
                    looppromises.push(fixPromise);
                    return fixPromise;
                });
            });
            return Parse.Promise.all(looppromises);
        });
        var promises = [statsPromise, oStatsPromise, grpPromise, looppromises];
        Parse.Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
            console.log("here");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite can be improved significantly by adopting a couple simple style rules: (1) there's no need to create a resolved promise and then chain to it (in fact, most would consider this an anti-pattern), (2) promises to be run together by iterating an array of operands is the perfect application of array .map (not reduce), (3) most importantly, smaller, testable, promise-returning functions always clears up the mystery.

Putting all that together, the main function can be as simple as this...

```
function loopOverOnce(agegroup) {
    let statsPromise = Stats(agegroup);
    let oStatsPromise = getOverallStats();
    let grpPromise = GetGroups(agegroup).then(function(groups) {
        return getStandingsAndFixturesForGroups(groups, agegroup);
    });
    return Parse.Promise.all([statsPromise, oStatsPromise, grpPromise]);
}
```

Let's write `getStandingsAndFixturesForGroups`.  It's only job will be map the groups and aggregate promises to do work on each...

```
function getStandingsAndFixturesForGroups(groups, agegroup) {
    let promises = groups.map(function(group) {
        return getStandingsAndFixturesForGroup(group, agegroup);
    });
    return Parse.Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Now, `getStandingsAndFixturesForGroup`, a function to do the async work on a single group, conditionally for part of the work...

```
function getStandingsAndFixturesForGroup(group, agegroup) {
    let promises = (group != "KO")?  [ Standings(agegroup, grp) ] : [];
    promises.push(GetFixtures(agegroup, group));
    return Parse.Promise.all(promises);  // this is your standings promise (conditionally) and fixtures promise
}
```

Done.  I'd test this code in the reverse order that it's presented here.

**EDIT** The OP also asks how to perform several promises, serially, interspersed with timeouts.  Here's my advice.

First, a slightly simpler version of your delay function, which is a good example when it *is* right to create a new promise (because there's nothing at bottom to call to get one)

```
function delay(interval) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {resolve();}, interval);
    });
};
```

And reducing is a good way to build a list of promises, including interspersed delays...

```
getAgeGroupList().then(function (loopAgeList) {
    loopAgeList.reduce(function(promise, agegroup) {
        return promise.then(function() {
            let promises = [loopOverOnce(agegroup), delay(15000)];
            return Promise.all(promises);
        });
    }, Promise.as());
});
```

A couple notes: this results in a sequence like loopOverOnce, timeout, loopOverOnce, timeout, ... etc.. If you'd like a timeout first, reverse the order of the little chain in the inner loop:

```
[ delay(15000), loopOverOnce(agegroup) ]
```

Final note is that all this could be made even shorter and prettier by adopting ES6 fat arrow syntax for anonymous functions, e.g.

```
loopAgeList.reduce((promise, agegroup) => {
    promise.then(() => Promise.all([loopOverOnce(agegroup), delay(15000)]));
}, Promise.as());
```

Comment: Your code is certainly much better structured than mine! Could you please explain your (1) in a bit more detail - why is it an anti-pattern? Should the `loopAgeList.reduce()` also be re-written using `map`?

Comment: @SimpleOne - :-) about creating promises then chaining, it's not so much bad as unnecessary. (This author considers it bad, see the second section in https://runnable.com/blog/common-promise-anti-patterns-and-how-to-avoid-them).  There's no need to create a promise if the thing you're calling returns a promise.  In the case of Parse, the internals return promises (often passed on from mongo).

Comment: @SimpleOne - my answer failed to address the loopAgeList part of your question.  I'll edit now to do so.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something here but the `loopAgeList.forEach()` does not give loopOverOnce, timeout, loopOverOnce, timeout, ... . Doesn't the `forEach` need to be chained so it waits after each iteration? If I add `console.log(agegroup)` on entry to the `forEach()` I quickly get a list of all age groups without a delay in between.

Comment: @SimpleOne, you're quite right!  I was so intent on scrubbing the reduces, that I missed the key point.  We can do this a number of ways, but not what I suggested, and using reduce is a good way to avoid nesting.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you pass a nested array to Promise.all:

```
  var promises = [statsPromise, oStatsPromise, grpPromise, looppromises];
```

Just flatten that:

```
 var promises = [statsPromise, oStatsPromise, grpPromise, ...looppromises];
 // Or
 var promises = [statsPromise, oStatsPromise, grpPromise].concat(looppromises);
```

However you still need to await `promise` somewhere to ensure that the chain finished its execution, otherwise `looppromise` will be empty.

---

All in all it might be better to use async / await to make everything much more readable:

```
(async function() {

  const ageGroups = await getAgeGroupList();

  const statsPromise = Stats(ageGroups[1]);
  const overallStatsPromise = getOverallStats();

  const groups = await GetGroups(ageGroups[1]);

  for(const group of groups) {
    const [standings, fixtures] = await Promise.all(
       Standings(ageGroups[1], group),
       GetFixtures(ageGroups[1], group)
    );
    // Do something with standings & fixtures
  }

   const [stats, overallStats] = await Promise.all(statsPromise, overallStatsPromise);

   // Do whatever you want with stats etc.
})();
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still gave me the same output ("here" is seen before looping completes).

Comment: @simpleOne can you use async await?

Comment: I'd rather not use async/await() unless it is the only solution

Comment: @simpleOne it would make it far more easy.

Comment: Please can you add a solution to show async await (I have never used it before).

Comment: @SimpleOne sure

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written it using `reduce` and seem to have it working. Comments on this would be welcome (i.e. are there any issues with this code).

```
        function loopOverOnce(agegroup) {
        var statsPromise = Stats(agegroup);
        var oStatsPromise = getOverallStats();

        var grpPromise = GetGroups(agegroup).then(function (groups) {
            function getStandingsAndFixtures(groups) {
                var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
                return groups.reduce(function (promise, grp) {
                    return promise.then(function (result) {
                        var standingsPromise = Parse.Promise.as();
                        if (grp != "KO") {
                            standingsPromise = Standings(agegroup, grp);
                        }
                        var fixPromise = GetFixtures(agegroup, grp);
                        console.log("fixPromise");
                        return Parse.Promise.all([standingsPromise, fixPromise]);
                    });
                }, promise);
            }
            var sfPromise = getStandingsAndFixtures(groups).then(function () { console.log("Test1") });
            return sfPromise;
        });

        return Parse.Promise.all([statsPromise, oStatsPromise, grpPromise]).then(function () { console.log("Test2") });
    }

    getAgeGroupList().then(function (loopAgeList) {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538473/using-settimeout-on-promise-chain
        function delay(t, v) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, v), t)
            });
        }

        var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
        loopAgeList.reduce(function (promise, agegroup) {
            return promise.then(function () {
                return delay(15000).then(function () {
                    return loopOverOnce(agegroup);
                });
            });
        }, promise);
    });
```

Comment: You may already be satisfied with how this is working, but there's some room for improvement illustrated in my answer.