# How to setTimeout axios response - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

Is it possible to `setTimeOut` the response of the following `axios` call?

```
export function getMetricsByContent(metricsParams) {
    console.log('metricsParams: ', metricsParams);
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.post(`/rbac/aa/reads/getReport`, metricsParams).then((response) => {
            console.log('metricsApiResponse: ', response);
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            return response;
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response) {
                return response.data.msg;
            } else {
                return "No content available";
            }

        })
            .catch((err) => {return err});
        };

}
```

Comment: you looking for `setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Our data is fetched');
      return response.data.msg;
    }, 1000)`

Comment: Why is your action creator returning something and not dispatching anything?

Comment: You could use [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) and race the request with  a [delay function that's described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39538518/1641941). The request cannot be cancelled once requested but you can just stop waiting for it.