# Print the data with the help of timer in ascending order

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, timer, es6-promise

Here is my code to print input data in the order of the `timer` values. I used promises:

```js
let a = [
    { data: 1000, timer: 3000 },
    { data: 2000, timer: 2000 },
    { data: 3000, timer: 1000 },
] 

const sleep = (m, d) =>
    new Promise((r,d) => setTimeout(r, m)).then((res) => {
        console.log(d);
    });

a.map(async (item) => {
   await sleep(item.timer, item.data);
});
```

The output should be

```
1000
2000
3000
```

but in the above attempt I am getting

```
3000
2000
1000
```

Why is it like that?

Comment: no, the order is correct ... you sleep 1000 before outputting 3000, 2000 before outputting 2000 and waiting 3000 before outputting 1000 ... the sleeps don't wait for each other

Comment: That's not how `setTimeout` works.  `setTimeout` expects to be handed a function to be called when the time expires.  Were you thinking of `delay`?

Comment: If you are trying to print in order after the timer, I would use setTimeout and wait for the response before setting the next timer.

Comment: @TimRoberts - `r` IS a function

Comment: You're right.  My bad.  Perhaps this can help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538473/using-settimeout-on-promise-chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is doing what is expected, but you are getting confused with the values for `data` and `timer`: these are the same values (1000, 2000, 3000), but ordered in opposite directions. One can easily interpret the output *data* as a *timeout*. When the output happens in increasing order of `timer`, then the output will be *decreasing* when you output the `data` properties (instead of the `timer` properties).

One way to clarify what happens is to not just print the *data*, but the whole object. Then it is clear that the objects **are** output in the correct order.

Some unrelated remarks:

- don't use `.map` when you are not creating an array.
- don't use `async/await` when you are not doing anything after that `await`, nor with the promise that is returned.
- don't use meaningless variable names like `r` and `d`, and avoid shadowing variables by using the same name for different scoped variables (like you have `d`).

I have applied those remarks to the code, but the essence is in changing the second argument that is passed to `sleep` and the formatting in `console.log`

```js
let arr = [
    { data: 1000, timer: 3000 },
    { data: 2000, timer: 2000 },
    { data: 3000, timer: 1000 },
] 

const sleep = (ms, obj) =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)).then(() => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    });

arr.forEach(item => sleep(item.timer, item));
```

Another remark is to not use `console.log` in such a generic function as `sleep`. It is better to get that `console.log` out of there, and place it in the main loop. I did not do this in the above code, as that would hide too much what the core solution was to your question, but I provide it here as illustration:

```js
let arr = [
    { data: 1000, timer: 3000 },
    { data: 2000, timer: 2000 },
    { data: 3000, timer: 1000 },
] 

const sleep = (ms, obj) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

arr.forEach(item => sleep(item.timer).then(() => console.log(item)));
```

Both in your code and this code, all three timers start at about the same time, before any asynchronous code gets executed. So the output of the object with `timer` equal to 1000 is expected to happen approximately 1 second after the start of the program, the one with 2000 is expected approximately 2 seconds after the start of the program, and the one with `timer` 3000 is expected to be output about 3 seconds after the start.