# How do I use a custom Promise with setTimeout that also handles errors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538473/using-settimeout-on-promise-chain) it is mentioned that I can create a custom Promise with `setTimeout` like below:

```js
const delay = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
```

My operation needs to be executed after 100ms so `t` will be `100` in my scenario.

I'm confused on how to use this though. The normal format of a Promise is `new Promise (resolve, reject)` but in the `delay` function only the `resolve` has been defined.
Here's my attempt:

```js
function numbersValidation(number1, number2) {
  if (!Number.isFinite(number1) || !Number.isFinite(number2)) {
    throw new Error('Only numbers are allowed');
  }
}

function add(number1, number2) {
  numbersValidation(number1, number2);
  return number1 + number2;
}

const addPromise = (number1, number2) => {
  delay(100)
  .then(result => result = add(number1, number2));
  .catch(err => reject(err));
};

// -----Test------

describe.only('promise calculator', () => {
  it('add works fine', done => {
    calculator.addPromise(1, 2).then(result => {
      try {
        assert.equal(3, result);
        done();
      } catch (e) {
        done(e);
      }
    });
  });
});
// AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 3 == false
```

This is quite wrong since my IDE is complaining about the structure, but can someone please point me in the right direction on how to use the delay function so that I make my `addPromise` function work?
Thank you

Comment: The delay arrow function is correct. Your IDE may be complaining because you have the `result` variable not used.

Comment: If your IDE complains about "something" than you should ask your IDE what it is talking about. That said... Why do you need a `Promise()` at all? A `setTimeout(() => add(number1, number2), 100)` does the same (because `addPromise()` doesn't return anyhting)

Comment: "*The normal format of a Promise is `new Promise (resolve, reject)`*" - no. "*but in the delay function only the resolve has been defined*" - so what? `setTimeout` doesn't cause any errors that would require you to reject the promise. So what errors do you want to handle?

Comment: @Bergi what if the input is a string and the error `Only numbers are allowed` is thrown, isn't that an error that I need to catch? Wouldn't that fall in the `rejected` category of a Promise?

Comment: @santa_cloudy that's something to catch in `addPromise` or in your test, but not in the `delay` function.

Answer (score 0):

`throw`ing inside a `.then` will result in the Promise it's connected to rejecting, which is what you want. Just leave off your `.catch(err => reject(err));` (since that part isn't needed at all, and `reject` isn't in scope there anyway).

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
function numbersValidation(number1, number2) {
  if (!Number.isFinite(number1) || !Number.isFinite(number2)) {
    throw new Error('Only numbers are allowed');
  }
}

function add(number1, number2) {
  numbersValidation(number1, number2);
  return number1 + number2;
}

const addPromise = (number1, number2) => (
  delay(100)
    .then(result => result = add(number1, number2))
);

addPromise(1, 2)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('success:', result === 3);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error:', error.message);
  });

addPromise(4, 'abc')
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('success:', result);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error:', error.message);
  });
```

Comment: I think you need to add `===` after result. But the code doesn't pass my test, I added the test snippet, can you please take a look and identify why your code works here in SO but not passing my test? Thanks

Comment: `addPromise` is a standalone function, not a property of a `calculator` object. Calling `addPromise(1, 2)` produces a Promise that resolves to `3`. `result === 3` results in `true`. That's what you want, isn't it? If you want to call a `done` function when there's an error, then put that in the `.catch` handler (don't use `try`/`catch`, use `Promise.prototype.catch`)

Comment: my `addPromise` is extracted as an object, in order to be accessed from the `test.js` file using `calculator.addPromise`.  Does this somehow affect the code structure my function should have?

Comment: You hadn't defined a `calculator` object before, so it seemed pretty suspicious - problems like those (defining something one way in a question, and in a different way in one's actual code) are frequent issues seen in Stack Overflow question.

Comment: `addPromise(1, 2)` produces a Promise that resolves to the number `3`. If that's what you want but it's still failing your test, either the test is faulty or the code has been miscopied, or something like that. As you can see from the snippet above, `result === 3` results in `true`

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code that you can adapt to your settings.

```
import { strict as assert } from 'node:assert';
function numbersValidation(number1, number2) {
  if (!Number.isFinite(number1) || !Number.isFinite(number2)) {
    throw new Error('Only numbers are allowed');
  }
}

function add(number1, number2) {
  numbersValidation(number1, number2);
  return number1 + number2;
}
const delay = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t))
const addPromise = (number1, number2) => {
  return delay(100)
  .then(result => result = add(number1, number2))
  .catch(e => Promise.reject(e))
};


// addPromise(1, 'a').then(result => {
//   try {
//     assert.equal(3, result);
//   } catch (e) {
//     console.log(e)
//   }
// })

addPromise(1, 2)
  .then(result => {
      assert.equal(3, result)
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Problems:

1. Typo in `.then(result => result = add(number1, number2));` the `;` needs to be removed.
2. `addPromise` should return the promises made by `delay`, cuz you are calling `then` on `calculator.addPromise(1, 2)`
3. Usually it is `Promise.reject` instead of `reject`, unless you expose it to the global context.
4. It is better to use a chaining catch other than the catch in the comments code, you can catch exceptions in the callback of `then`
5. the delayed promise only has `resolve`, cuz it doesn't need to reject, time will pass 100ms anyway unless our universe might be frozen and the delay will reject.

"No, I can't resolve, cuz time stopped".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! The code still doesn't work for me, when I console log it shows me Promise { <pending> } and I think that's why I'm still getting AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 3 == false :/

Comment: `.catch(e => Promise.reject(e))` is pointless, you should just omit that

Comment: @Bergi It is just a demonstration that we can catch errors from `numbersValidation`, but we don't handle it and reject it to the upper level.

Comment: @santa_cloudy That means the promise has not been resolved yet, ensure the assertion is in the `then` 's callback.