# Javascript: how to get one function to run after another completes

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I'm new to javascript and promises.  I'm trying to get one function not to start running until the first function has completed.

In this case, I want the "dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete" function to run AFTER the "delayGreet" function.

```
function delayGreet() {
    setTimeout(greet, 1000);
}

function greet() {
    para1.textContent = "Hi there!";
}

function createPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(delayGreet));
}

function dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete() {
    para2.textContent = "Please dont do before";
}

function callMethod() {
    createPromise().then(dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete);
}

callMethod();`
```

I've tried putting the functions within a promise and use the .then() method.  However, I'm unable to get it to work.

Comment: Perhaps you need this: [Using setTimeout in a promise chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538473/using-settimeout-on-promise-chain/39538518#39538518).

Comment: If the two functions are returning promises, couldn't you simply chain them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is accurate:

*"I want the "dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete" function to run AFTER the "delayGreet" function"*

I think you want `dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete` to run after `greet`, which is different.

`setTimeout` does not create a promise, it simply schedules a function to run. If you want something to run immediately after that, then schedule that as well.

```js
function greet() {
    console.log("Hi there!");
}

function dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete() {
    console.log("Please dont do before");
}

function delayGreet() {
    function greetThenDoSomethingElse() {
      greet();
      dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete();
    }
    setTimeout(greetThenDoSomethingElse, 1000);
}

delayGreet();
```

---

Here's a solution with a generic callback:

```js
function greet() {
    console.log("Hi there!");
}

function dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete() {
    console.log("Please dont do before");
}

function delayGreetThenCallback(callback) {
    function greetThenCallback() {
      greet();
      callback();
    }
    setTimeout(greetThenCallback, 1000);
}

delayGreetThenCallback(dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete);
```

---

And here's one with a promise:

```js
function greet() {
  console.log('Hi there!');
}

function dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete() {
  console.log('Please dont do before');
}

function delayGreet() {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      greet();
      resolve();
    }, 1000)
  );
}

delayGreet().then(dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete);
```

Comment: Where did the promise go?

Comment: @Bergi They don't need one, unless I'm misunderstanding. I believe they just want the second function to run after the timeout.

Comment: "*I'm new to JS and promises*", as well as the tags [promise] and [async-await] on the question, made me assume that the OP wants to learn how to do this with promises. And imo they indeed *should* do this with promises, it's the right way to approach this problem.

Comment: @Bergi maybe, depends on the use case.

Comment: Actually, what i do want is a generic "function2" to run after "function1" is complete.  Is there an event that triggers after "function1" runs if a promise is set up?

Comment: @gbrother54 sure, I edited to include a solution that takes a generic callback, as well as one that uses a promise.

Comment: @gbrother54 Yes, the promise fulfillment "event". It's what you're listening for when you use `.then(dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete)`. However the promise does not automatically fulfill when "function1" is complete (unless it's an `async function` with `await`), the function must create, return, and later resolve the promise.

Comment: Excellent.  I got it to work in this short example I gave.  I'm going to see if i can get it to work in the more complex thing I am working on.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

.then takes a callback function with the result (resolve of promise) as a paramater

```
createPromise.then(res => dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete())
```

Comment: This does not seem to have anything to do with the problem in the question which is: *I want the "dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete" function to run AFTER the "delayGreet" function.*

Comment: `dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete` **is** a function - `.then(dontDoUntilDelayIsComplete)` is fine