How can one handle racing between two callbacks on the same event that can be triggered multiple times?
I have two callbacks that need to be put on the same change event on the same item. For reasons that are not worth going into, I need to have these callbacks in separate on, I cannot unify them under a single on call. So I need these on calls to stay separate, for example:
$('body').on('change', '#my-div', function1);
$('body').on('change', '#my-div', function2); 

Now, I have an AJAX call inside function1. I would like for function2 to always execute after the execution of function1 is done, including after an AJAX response has been received inside function1. I asked ChatGPT and it advised me to use $.Deferred():
let function1Deferred = $.Deferred();
function function1() {
    function1Deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your-url', // Replace with your URL
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Function1 AJAX request completed");
            function1Deferred.resolve(); 
        },
        error: function() {
            function1Deferred.reject();
        }
    });
}

function function2() {
    function1Deferred.done(function() {
        console.log("Function2 is now executing after function1 has completed.");
    });
}

To my mind, though, this only solves the problem the first time the change event gets triggered, because there's no guarantee that function1 will run first, before function2 - and therefore there's no guarantee that, on the second and third etc. trigger of the change event, the line function1Deferred = $.Deferred(); inside function1 will run before function2 runs, so function2 might well be the first to run, and run to the end, on the subsequent triggers of the change event.
Am I missing something, is the code actually achieving what I want and I'm just missing something about how Deferred works under the hood? If yes, what am I missing? If not, how can I solve my problem and ensure function2 always runs after function1 on subsequent triggers of the event, not just on the first one?
I just want to emphasize again that I need the calls of the on function to stay separate, I cannot use a single on('change', '#my-div', newFunction) call, this is not a solution for my problem in its larger context.

$.Deferred is an earlier version of a promise. That's the reason you shouldn't ask ChatGPT about programming problems. If you can use a deferred/promise, you can remove the second .on and move the code into the callback

I agree that chatgpt has many issues for programming questions too. I just use it as a tool, sometimes it works, it produces something verifiably correct, other times it doesn't. I was just signaling that I also tried this before asking the question.

You could also mention that you asked your hamster and your grandmother. It doesn't add any value to your question. It could even cause your question to be downvoted and closed because AI generated text is explicitly forbidden and as you described, the code is AI generated. Policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned

As presented, the code will not necessarily do what you want. If function2 triggers first:

The first time, it will reference the initial deferred object, which will never be completed, so function 2 will never run;
On subsequent runs, it will reference the deferred object from the previous run, which is already completed, so it will run before function 1.

Here's a demo which explicitly sets the deferred object to null to make it more obvious. If you click the "run F2+F1" button, you'll get a "function1Deferred is null" error.


const output = document.getElementById("output");

let function1Deferred = null;

function function1() {
    output.append("Running function 1\n");
    function1Deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(() => {
        output.append("Function 1 complete\n");
        function1Deferred.resolve();
    }, 1000);
}

function function2() {
    function1Deferred.done(() => {
        output.append("Running function 2\n");
    });
}

document.getElementById("run1").addEventListener("click", () => {
    try {
        function1Deferred = null;
        function1();
        function2();
    } catch (e) {
        output.append(`Error: ${e}\n`);
    }
});

document.getElementById("run2").addEventListener("click", () => {
    try {
        function1Deferred = null;
        function2();
        function1();
    } catch (e) {
        output.append(`Error: ${e}\n`);
    }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
<p>
  <button id="run1" type="button">Run F1+F2</button>
  <button id="run2" type="button">Run F2+F1</button>
</p>



Given the constraints, the simplest option is probably to wrap the function2 body in a setTimeout call:
setTimeout(() => function1Deferred.done(() => {
    output.append("Running function 2\n");
}), 0);

This will return control to the calling function, allowing the other handlers to execute, before registering the done callback on the deferred object.
Updated demo


const output = document.getElementById("output");

let function1Deferred = null;

function function1() {
    output.append("Running function 1\n");
    function1Deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(() => {
        output.append("Function 1 complete\n");
        function1Deferred.resolve();
    }, 1000);
}

function function2() {
    setTimeout(() => function1Deferred.done(() => {
        output.append("Running function 2\n");
    }), 0);
}

document.getElementById("run1").addEventListener("click", () => {
    try {
        function1Deferred = null;
        function1();
        function2();
    } catch (e) {
        output.append(`Error: ${e}\n`);
    }
});

document.getElementById("run2").addEventListener("click", () => {
    try {
        function1Deferred = null;
        function2();
        function1();
    } catch (e) {
        output.append(`Error: ${e}\n`);
    }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
<p>
  <button id="run1" type="button">Run F1+F2</button>
  <button id="run2" type="button">Run F2+F1</button>
</p>



Now, whichever button you click, you will not see the "Running function 2" message until after the "Function 1 complete" message.

Also, as @jabaa mentioned in the comments, $.Deferred is a precursor to the JavaScript Promise. Combined with async functions, you could simplify this code even more:


const output = document.getElementById("output");

/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/39538518/124386 */
const delay = (timeout, result = null) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, timeout, result));

let function1Deferred = null;

async function function1() {
  output.append("Running function 1\n");
  const { promise, resolve, reject } = Promise.withResolvers();
  function1Deferred = promise;

  await delay(1000);

  output.append("Function 1 complete\n");
  resolve();
}

async function function2() {
  await delay(0);
  await function1Deferred;
  output.append("Running function 2\n");
}

document.getElementById("run1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  try {
    function1Deferred = null;
    function1();
    function2();
  } catch (e) {
    output.append(`Error: ${e}\n`);
  }
});

document.getElementById("run2").addEventListener("click", () => {
  try {
    function1Deferred = null;
    function2();
    function1();
  } catch (e) {
    output.append(`Error: ${e}\n`);
  }
});
<pre id="output"></pre>
<p>
  <button id="run1" type="button">Run F1+F2</button>
  <button id="run2" type="button">Run F2+F1</button>
</p>




This works amazingly. But what does exactly setTimeout do to achieve this?

@rosecabbagedragon It queues up the callback function to run in "the next event cycle" - ie, once all of the event handler functions have been executed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful



var formAjax = (formElement,beforeSubmit)=>{
    var dfrd = $.Deferred();
    $(formElement).ajaxSubmit({
        beforeSubmit,
        success:dfrd.resolve,
        error:dfrd.rejected
    });
    return dfrd.promise();
};
<form id="frmPost" method="post" action="path-to-submit">
<input type="text" id="isian">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="hasil"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-form@4.3.0/dist/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#frmPost').submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    formAjax('#frmPost',function(){
      if( $('#isian').val()=='' ){
        alert('empty');
        $('#isian').focus();
        return false;
      }else return true;
    }).then(()=>{
      $('#hasil').html('success submit');
    }).fail(err=>{
      $('#hasil').html(err.message);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>



me using jquery.form
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-form@4.3.0/dist/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

var formAjax = (formElement,beforeSubmit)=>{
    var dfrd = $.Deferred();
    $(formElement).ajaxSubmit({
        beforeSubmit,
        success:dfrd.resolve,
        error:dfrd.rejected
    });
    return dfrd.promise();
};

